# steps for creating relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables: user,posts and followee_posts.

I have set a model called 'followee' that should relate followee to a user.

Also have pivot table that contains 'follower_id' and 'followee_id'.

I have also set a model called 'Followee.php'

I have set the many-to-many relatioship inside it.

Now what else I need to do so a user can press a button and the user selected will be added to the followee pivot table?

Code (in the view):

```
    @foreach($mutuals as $mutual)
 <a href="#" class="button button-3d" name="make_follow">Follow User</a>
{!! $mutual->user->name; !!} 
@endforeach
```

migration:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('followee_posts', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
            $table->integer('follower_id')->unsigned(); 
            $table->integer('followee_id')->unsigned(); 
            $table->foreign('follower_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('followee_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Followee.php (Model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Followee extends Model
{
public function followee()
{
    return this->BelongsToMany('App\user');

}

 protected $table = 'followee_posts'; 
 protected $primaryKey='follower_id';
```

Comment: Well, first you'd need a button :). But joking aside, what have you tried so far? Have you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) on relations and got stuck somewhere?

Comment: Ha! :) okay so I do have already foreach loop that shows the user other users he can add (with a 'follow' button).

Comment: Yep, can confirm. You need a button.

Comment: Yes I am reading the docs and stuck right after the relationship is defined.
what's next? I already have set the model that points out that basically says: many users can follow many users. Here's the model code (Followee.php):
http://paste.ofcode.org/qSqaxRMttXxYDeVTPxfLkK

So now I need to let the user to add other users to the followee pivot table.

Comment: have you created your view with the button?

Comment: Yes I did. It is a 'follow user' button that does nothing at the moment.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far (that includes the view file) so we have a context on which to provide suggestions. And please edit your question to include he code, don't link to external paste bins.

Comment: Just did it. What do you think?

Comment: did you try: $user->followee()->attach($id_user);

Comment: @sam12 just added that to the controller and it looks like this: `protected function followee_post() { $user =Auth::user(); $user->followee()->attach($id_user); }`  I now need to add the followee to the pivot table right? how do I do that? RIght now I am encoutering an error:
**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::followee()**